# How do I generate coupons template in Excel or Word based on item details and quantity (details below)?

Tags: excel, templates, ms-word, spreadsheet, mailmerge

A master sheet with this data below

| Item Name | Item Code | Item Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | F01 | 50 |
| Item2 | F02 | 10 |

From the above, I would like to generate printable coupons - totally 60, that can be cut and distributed for an event. ( the items are food names).

Eg, one of them would have this information

"**Item1 : F01-001**" and "**Item1 : F01-050**" ( 50 of these) AND
"**Item2 : F02-001**" and "**Item2 : F01-010**" ( 10 of these)

Comment: Mail-merge is perfect solution for it. Design your coupon format in MS-Word sand link the excel sheet to that format via mail-merge method. Then you can make thousands of coupon in minutes.

Comment: @Harun24hr «Mail-merge is perfect solution for it» Word's mailmerge cannot do this without making major changes to the data source.

Comment: @jackrabb1t This is will require a macro to implement. For some code to get you started, see: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/additional-mail-merge-items-dependent-on-value.1056230/